# Trigger to insert sysdate after an insert in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I tried using the following but apparently it's invalid SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QUESTION_DATE BEFORE INSERT ON QUESTION 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO QUESTION(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) 
VALUES (SYSDATE);
END;
```

The Question table looks like this so far:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION
(   
    QUESTION_ID             INTEGER not null,
    LATEST_QUESTION         INTEGER not null,
    CREATED_USER_ID         INTEGER not null,
    CREATED_TIMESTAMP       TIMESTAMP not null,     
    CONSTRAINT PK_QUESTION  PRIMARY KEY (QUESTION_ID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE QUESTION_ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCYCLE NOCACHE NOORDER;

CREATE TRIGGER QUESTION_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON QUESTION 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT QUESTION_ID_SEQ.nextval
INTO :new.QUESTION_ID
FROM dual;
END;
```

I'm using Toad for Oracle V9.0.1.8 if that's relevant

Comment: Give more info.  Is the column that you trying to set to sysdate is the same table as the row that you just inserted?  For example, if you table has ColumnFirst and ColumnTheDate, are you attempting to set ColumnTheDate equal to sysdate for the row that you just inserted?

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to set ColumnTheDate to Sysdate for the row I just inserted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you probably want this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QUESTION_DATE BEFORE INSERT ON QUESTION 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :NEW.CREATED_TIMESTAMP := SYSDATE;
END;
```

Your trigger tries to insert another row into QUESTION, which would fire the trigger and...

Comment: I'm still getting a "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" when trying to add the trigger

Comment: Does your trigger look **exactly** like mine?

Comment: Yup, I copy-and-pasted the statement

Comment: Oops, never mind! I forgot to execute as script and instead ran it in the editor. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20):

Dont use a trigger to set a default value in Oracle.  Instead, use "DEFAULT" on the column.
Here is an exmple column

```
CREATED_TIMESTAMP  TIMESTAMP  DEFAULT SYSDATE  NOT NULL,
```

Comment: I agree. Just be aware that if it's an existing table the entire table will be locked while Oracle populates the new column.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not update the timestamp on updates.

Comment: This only works for simple default values.  If you need to call a PL/SQL function to generate the default value (e.g. DBMS_RANDOM to produce a random sequence of characters) then `DEFAULT` cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

:new.created_timestamp := sysdate

Instead of insert.

The insert is already occurring, no need to do it again.

You could also make sysdate the default for the column, but that would allow for the value to be overridden in the insert statement.